# DATE_FORMAT vs LIKE performance comparison in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So, the situation is - In the below query, there is a JOIN between 2 tables.

```
SELECT saza.required_impressions as required_impressions, saza.requested_impressions as allocated_impressions, SUM(ahs.impressions) as delivered_impressions, saza.zone_id as zone_id 
FROM ox_data_summary_ad_zone_assoc as saza 
INNER JOIN ox_data_summary_ad_hourly as ahs 
ON saza.ad_id = ahs.ad_id AND saza.zone_id = ahs.zone_id 
WHERE saza.ad_id = 18867 AND DATE_FORMAT(saza.interval_start, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-12-21' 
GROUP BY saza.zone_id 
ORDER BY saza.zone_id;
```

- Each of these tables is holding humongous amount of data (Approx. 167,334,535 rows each).
- If you observe, there is `DATE_FORMAT()` function used in `WHERE` clause. So, the table data is compared against this value.
- This query is taking almost 16 mins to complete the execution.

**My Questions,**
 1. What performance difference will be there if I use `LIKE '2015-12-21%'` instead of `DATE_FORMAT()`?
 2. Is there any other better way that I could write this query?

Comment: Did you check that the performance is affected by the date comparison part only?

Comment: No I did not. I was trying to reduce the time taken by all the ways that I could. I thought this might be one of the causes.

Comment: what you see when you run 'explain <your query>'?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru - Please find the result of explain in this link http://pastebin.com/M3wZbahA

Comment: It seems there are no indexes created in both tables. Create one of interval_start. MySQL "Like" uses index if query has '2015-12-21%' (but not '%2015-12-21%'). Does ad_id and zone_id or primary keys?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru - There is a non-unique index for ad_id and zone_id respectively.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is an index on date_time as well. Refer this - http://pastebin.com/EXDZgcz5

Comment: Try creating an composite index on (ad_id, interval_start) will solve this problem.

Comment: I would suggest trying to use _WHERE saza.ad_id = 18867 AND saza.interval_start BETWEEN  '2015-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-21 23:59:59'_

Comment: @Kickstart - What difference would there be in processing between `BETWEEN` and `DATE_FORMAT` ?

Comment: @MuraliMopuru - I think composite index might solve the problem. Will try it and update.

Comment: Date format requires using a function on every single row of the table, effectively stopping any index being used. Between specifying the full date / time means the values on the table can be compared directly on a relevant index.

Comment: @Kickstart - Agreed. So I will try with `BETWEEN` clause once I introduce the composite index suggested by Murali. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your support guys.

I found that, since the table I was querying was very large, it would take same amount of time whether I use `Between` or `LIKE` operators.

Finally I resolved this issue by querying 24 times for hourly data and merging the data to day-array in my application logic. In my case, PHP.

Here is the comparison -

**One Day's data query with `BETWEEN` or `LIKE` operator** -

Query Response time : 16 mins apprx.

**One Hour's data query with `BETWEEN` or `LIKE` operator** -

Query Response time of 1 hour : 2 secs * 24 hours = 48 Secs apprx.

HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE AT LEAST.